# Custom Google Charts

Tags: php, graph, charts

I need to create the following type of Chart using Google.
Can anyone please help?

I know how to create the column graph to show runs but how do i show the wickets that have fallen in that over?

Please help. Thanks.

```
y
|    -
|    |
|  - | -
|  | | -
|  | | |
0-------------------x
```

Comment: Divide the goals by number of red balls potted, and multiply by converted tries

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly should the chart look like but maybe try this library for [generating charts using Google Chart API](https://github.com/martinsik/GoogleChartGenerator) in PHP or check the [bar chart](https://github.com/martinsik/GoogleChartGenerator/wiki/Bar-chart) section right away and see if it's what you are looking for.